# Why is the maximum data rate of 802.11p lower than 802.11a although 802.11p has a higher frequency band?

Tags: wifi, 802.11p

In Vehicle to vehicle communication, high speeds of nodes require low latency. (Latency is
the time interval between sending messages by a sender node and receiving
message by a receiver node.) It should be very low. To achieve the low latency
requirement in Vehicle to vehicle communication, the speed of data transmission should be high. Highspeed data transmission needs high-frequency ranges.

Frequency band of IEEE 802.11p is 5,9 Ghz and frequency band of IEEE 802.11a is 5 Ghz.
Why is the maximum data rate of 802.11p lower than 802.11a although 802.11p has a higher frequency band?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason is a lower channel bandwidth of 802.11p (10Mhz) compared to 802.11a (20Mhz).. Shannon theorem states the maximum data rate that can be transmitted in a channel depends on a given bandwidth..